# Python Curses, slow refresh on different consecutive colors

Tags: python, macos, performance, refresh, curses

Using python->curses module, I experience a very slow
draw/refresh if I chage the string color atribute a lot.
I wrote the same program in C++ and had no issue.
Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import curses
import locale

# Inint global console config
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')


def main(stdscr):
    curses.start_color()
    curses.use_default_colors()
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_YELLOW, 0)
    curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_RED, 0)

    max_rows, max_cols = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    max_cont = max_rows * max_cols
    try:
        for i in range(1, max_cont):
            stdscr.addstr('█', curses.color_pair(i % 2 + 1))
    except curses.ERR:
        pass
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getch()

curses.wrapper(main)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is slow because the program sends an escape sequence to change the color for every cell on the screen.

That is, instead of just sending `'█'` (a 3-byte UTF-8 string), it sends in addition the color information.  In readable form (with [`unmap`](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:unmap)), something like this:

```
\E[31m
\E[40m\342\226\210
\E[33m
\E[40m\342\226\210
\E[31m
\E[40m\342\226\210
...
```

because curses writes both the foreground and background colors for each cell (since a few terminals cannot do them independently).  That's 10 bytes for escape sequences and 3 bytes for data, making it slower by about 4 times.

Comment: But why the same code written in C++ is very fast? And even if I change '█' character with for example 'A' is still slow.

Comment: Python is an interpreter, and has more work to do than a compiler application in C++.

Comment: I don't think that the amount of data that is sent is the issue here, because as I said is slower only when the colours alternate. If I use only one color pair, the amount of data sent is the same but it works super fast.

Comment: If you use only one color pair, there is no switching of colors, no escape sequences.

Comment: I have the same issue but with app written in C++, is there any way of speeding up refreshing a multicolor screen?